# How to enumerate per-Forest Active Directory domains in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, dns

This code enumerate Active Directory  domains, if the mahine on which is running is part of the forest.

```
public static ArrayList EnumerateDomains()
{
    ArrayList alDomains = new ArrayList();
    Forest currentForest = Forest.GetCurrentForest();
    DomainCollection myDomains = currentForest.Domains;

    foreach (Domain objDomain in myDomains)
    {
        alDomains.Add(objDomain.Name);
    }
    return alDomains;
}
```

Is it posible to enumerate domains which are part of some other forest ?

What is the difference between forest and global catalog ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic above should work (provided permissions are OK) if you replace the setting of `currentForest` with a call to [Forest.GetForest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.forest.getforest.aspx) that identifies the forest whose domains you wish to enumerate.

```
DirectoryContext context = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Forest,
    "dns-name-of-target-forest");
Forest currentForest = Forest.GetForest(context);
```

If you don't have permission but do know someone who does, there are [DirectoryContext constructor overrides](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141478.aspx) that allow you to specify an alternate name and password.

The relationship of global catalog  to forest is detailed [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc728188%28WS.10%29.aspx). In short, a forest is an Active Directory (AD) abstraction for grouping of AD objects.  A global catalog (if the forest has one) is a distributed data repository that is required in order for certain types of operations to be done on that forest.